# How do I solve the following issue with async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a javascript array. I need to process each element of this array and then store the entire array into an object store. The kind of processing I do on the elements should be async. as shown in the following method.

```
var x = [ele1,ele2,ele3] ; 

x.forEach(function(ele,index){

if(ele == "some specific object"){
MyAPI.process("command",function(result){ 

x[index] = result; 
});

database.store(x);
```

Comment: What does MyAPI.process do? If it mostly ends up calling an AJAX service, the browser will already execute that request asynchronously. If you need to do processing in Javascript, use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers)

Comment: The first parameter to `forEach` should be the callback, not the array itself.

Comment: This is assuming you're working in a browser. (You didn't really specify your environment.) If you're working in Node.js then the above doesn't apply at all

Answer (score 0):

The problem when calculating asynchronously is that the elements aren't processed in order. The key would be to keep track of the number of results that have been processed then, and only then, call the store method.  The most effective way is to move the call to the store method into the callback.  That way you can call it directly after the check for the last element succeeds rather than having to do a busy/wait while checking the flag condition.  Another possibility would be to raise an event when the last element is processed and have the store take place in the event handler (or something similar).

```
var x = [ele1,ele2,ele3] ; 
var expectedResults = 0;
var results = 0;

x.forEach(x,function(ele,index) {
     if (ele == "some specific object") {
         ++expectedResults;
     }
});

x.forEach(x,function(ele,index){

    if (ele == "some specific object"){
        MyAPI.process("command",function(result){ 
           x[index] = result;
           if (++results == expectedResults) {
              database.store(x);
           }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I am not process "all" the elements in X. seconds the database.store operation can not happen inside the loop, it needs to happen outside it.

Comment: You'd need to figure out how many of the element you will process then, check the number of results against that value. You're not strictly calling it "inside" the loop - it's actually being within the callback function, but only after all the results that will be processed have been.  I've updated the example.